# Is it better to use XNodeEqualityComparer or XElement.DeepEquals to compare xml objects?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to compare two xml documents.

Assume that each of the following XElement's load from a `Stream`:

```
XElement actualElement = XElement.Load(actual);
XElement expectedElement = XElement.Load(expected);
```

Using that, which of the following two is better:

```
XNodeEqualityComparer comparer = new XNodeEqualityComparer();
comparer.Equals(actualElement, expectedElement);
```

or

```
XElement.DeepEquals(actualElement, expectedElement);
```

I know that the second option is shorter, but I am more interested in whether or not you get any speed improvements or better/deeper comparison when using one or the other. The comparison itself needs to compare the elements, attributes, and all values between the two xml documents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [XNodeEqualityComparer.Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348073.aspx) simply calls the [XNode.DeepEquals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx). So there is no difference between the two calls.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose if I had actually fired up Reflector and looked at XNodeEqualityComparer.Equals, I would have seen this: public bool Equals(XNode x, XNode y)
{
    return XNode.DeepEquals(x, y);
}. Doh!